# What is causing this on my pepper plant?

Tags: diseases, peppers

Can someone help me identify what is happening to my poor peppers?

[image]

Comment: Looks like your post got about as much attention as mine. https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/62787/whats-wrong-with-these-carmen-peppers did you solve your issue?