# What's wrong with these carmen peppers?

Tags: fungus, peppers

I found a brown soggy spot on the middle of a carmen pepper in my garden and figured it got damaged somehow and was rotting.  But today I found another on the same plant.  A quick, uneducated internet search suggested it may be anthracnose.  Because it's on the side and not the bottom it doesn't sound like blossom end rot.  Appreciate any identification,  or control tips.

For what it's worth, I live in hardiness zone 5 and it's been in the 80s (degrees F) and very dry this week.  I water daily, usually in the evenings.

[image]

Update a week later: a second pepper seems to be starting the same problem.  I removed both fruits.  Here is a close-up.

[image]

[image]